# How to get temporary disabled preferences in AsyncTask?

Tags: android

I am building an app that have Preferences in settings activity. There are two groups of preferences, one group for app settings, and another is for user's settings which should be synchronized with remote webserver.

One preference is represented as a button, which is running an `AsyncTask` of sending data to backend:

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/save_btn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:text="Save Settings" />
```

I want to partly disable preferences while AsyncTask is running, and re-enable them for edit, when async task is finished, how can I do it ?

My thought is to get a context of activity in async task, is this a correct approach ?

```
public class SavePreferences extends Preference {


    // constructor code is skipped

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                (new UpdateFilterTask(v)).execute();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and constructor of AsyncTask:

```
public UpdateFilterTask(View btn) {
    super();
    this.button = btn;
    rootView = btn.getRootView();
    ...
}
```

Comment: you could set a `static boolean Busy`, OnClick set it to `true` if not busy and disable the button (for styling purposes) and in `OnPostExcute` set Busy to `false`. So when the user clicks again, check if Busy is true and just return or repeat..

Comment: So basically you want your `save button` to be disabled when `AsyncTask` is Running?

Comment: save button an other preferences that are related to filter settings - I want to restrict user from modifying settings while they are updating. Other settings related to app settings should be editable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple approaches you could take in this scenario

1. Send Broadcast using LocalBroadcastManager in the postExecute() callback of AsyncTask

   **LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION_NAME));**

In your Activity register the receiver, to get notified once AsyncTask finishes with doInBackground().

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // **enable the preferences here**

            }
        };
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_NAME));
```

**Note: The ACTION_NAME should be same when your register the receiver and once you broadcast from AsyncTask**

2. You can also define an **Interface** in your **AsyncTask class** and have it implemented in your Activity class. Start the AsyncTask from Activity passing the reference, then in AsyncTask class, you can have it typeCasted to the Interface object. Lastly, using the same interface object you can call its method(defined in Activity) inside postExecute() callback.

Hope it helps.